# Organizar slider Boostrap responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente HTML de un slider múltiple en Boostrap

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container my-4">

  <hr class="my-4">

  <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
  <div id="multi-item-example" class="carousel slide carousel-multi-item" data-ride="carousel">

    <!--Controls-->
    <div class="controls-top">
      <a class="btn-floating" href="#multi-item-example" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a class="btn-floating" href="#multi-item-example" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!--/.Controls-->

    <!--/.Indicators-->

    <!--Slides-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <!--First slide-->
      <div class="carousel-item active">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card mb-2">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
            <div class="card mb-2">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(18).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
            <div class="card mb-2">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(35).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
            <div class="card mb-2">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(35).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card mb-2">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
            <div class="card mb-2">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(18).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
            <div class="card mb-2">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(35).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
            <div class="card mb-2">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(35).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>


      <!--/.First slide-->
    </div>
    <!--/.Slides-->
  </div>
  <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->


</div>
```

Y funciona perfecto, se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo veo desde celular, se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se muestra de forma hacia abajo y cuando doy en la flecha de mover slider, mueve de a cuatro, pues lo que quiero es que solo se vea de a uno y cada vez que voy rotando el slider, se muestre de a uno.

Comment: Creo el problema está en el JavaScript, si es así, podrías mostrarlo aunque sea compartido desde [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @BrahimKhallota , https://jsfiddle.net/andres77u77/snkf4oxb/5/ , yo no uso JS para hacer el movimiento, como tal es de boostrap

Comment: Veo que tienes agrupados los 4 elementos en el mismo `<div class="carousel-item">` eso hace que sean un único elemento dentro del slider. No tengo mucha experiencia, solo puedo ayudarte con eso, hasta que lea el post alguien más experto en ello

Comment: Para lograr lo que deseas, debes hacer uso de las media queries y también de los eventos del carousel. Estás usando la librería MDB por casualidad?

Comment: @JheymanMejia , El codigo lo vi en MDB, pero como tal es la de boostrap

Comment: lo has visto en un celular real?

Comment: @RuslanLópez , asi es, el problema es que muestra tambien en el celular el primer producto de cada grupo de 4 productos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para mi funciona este código, en ambas vistas, en este caso el slide es de 4 en 4 pero se puede hacer que se vaya corriendo de 1 en 1, déjame un comentario si necesitas esta variante y te la agrego también

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container my-4">

    <hr class="my-4">

    <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
    <div id="multi-item-example" class="carousel slide carousel-multi-item" data-ride="carousel">

      <!--Slides-->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <!--First slide-->
        <div class="carousel-item active">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
              <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(18).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
              <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(35).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
              <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(35).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!--/.First slide-->

        <!--Second slide-->
        <div class="carousel-item">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/City/4-col/img%20(60).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
              <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/City/4-col/img%20(47).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
              <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/City/4-col/img%20(48).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
              <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/City/4-col/img%20(47).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!--/.Second slide-->

        <!--Third slide-->
        <div class="carousel-item">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Food/4-col/img%20(53).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
              <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Food/4-col/img%20(45).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
              <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Food/4-col/img%20(51).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 clearfix d-none d-md-block">
              <div class="card mb-2">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Food/4-col/img%20(53).jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!--/.Third slide-->

      </div>
      <!--/.Slides-->

    </div>
    <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
  </div>

</body>
```

EDIT:
aqui hay tambien bien documentado un codigo incluso con demo no se si sea esto lo que buscas
https://azmind.com/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-items/

Comment: Como tal, en vista escritorio va de 4 en 4, al verlo en celular, solo me muestra el primero de cada grupo de 4 y pues en celular debe ir de uno en uno

Comment: supongo que ya hayas visto esto https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/carousel/ pero el problema es que el ejemplo que ponen para pasar de 1 en 1 al menos a mi no me esta funcionando, y el agrega un script para ello, la otra opcion es hacerlo mediante javascript y media query para dar formato cuando este en vista movil. Mira tambien el sitio que agregue al final

Comment: asi es, me guié del MDB, pero ando con el lio, y no quiero reestructura todo el avance que llevo :c

Comment: En mi opinión el link que puse en el EDIT es lo mejor que pude encontrar y esta bastante bien explicado y cumple con lo que necesitas

Comment: @AndresRodriguez como te dejé en un comentario, necesitas escribir reglas media queries específicas y además crear el script de los eventos según esas reglas. Debes reestructurarlo, si es lo que deseas.

Comment: @JheymanMejia , entiendo, gracias a todos